# Finding Algorithm complexity in terms of big O

Tags: algorithm

what will be the run time of the following code segment in terms of big O? [assuming `f1(n)=O(n)`]

```
function Recurse(A[1..n])
        f1(n)
        t1 <-- Recurse(A[1..(n-1)])
        t2 <-- Recurse(A[(2..n])
        return (t1+t2)
end function
```

is it `O(n)` ?? or something else?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is theoretical not practical. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RaymondChen please highlight some specific text on the SO pages that says a question like this is off topic.

Comment: @chiastic-security "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @chastic-security Right there on [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) in big letters. "Get answers to practical, detailed questions." Theoretical questions are not practical. Also number four on the "Do not ask" list: Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Comment: Looks directly related to writing computer programs to me. OP wants to find out algorithm runtime for a fairly specific type of recursion.

Comment: @RaymondChen It looks directly related to writing computer programs to me too. And it is immensely practical: knowing the algorithmic complexity of your algorithm tells you whether it'll be fit for purpose in the context in which you're deploying it. Do you think it's a practical issue that quicksort is O(n log n) and bubblesort is O(n^2)? And are you going to try to close [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o) too (2367 votes, 2088 faves)?

Comment: Wiring the code is programming. But this is purely a theoretical level. There is no practical problem being solved. It's an unmotivated exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This is exponential in invocations of `f1`: `O(2^n)` invocations. So if `f1` is `O(n)` then this will come out as `O(n 2^n)`.

You've got n steps, and at each point, it subdivides into two branches. It's the same as a complete binary tree of height n.

Comment: not true in general; if f1(n) had some other order of growth, then that term would contribute.

Comment: Then what would be the accurate result? @ chiastic-security

Comment: Well, corrected the argument anyway, at the cost of making the answer less accurate.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat how do you mean?

Comment: agreed... I'm not sure your corrected answer is accurate. You have to be careful with these O(n) calculations.

Comment: @JasonS There are `O(2^n)` steps, each of size `O(n)`. That is pretty clear. I'm happy to hear counter-arguments, but they'll need to be more specific than "you have to be careful". I've been careful.